# How to create a window similar to a window with model properties in autodesk-viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I load two models into different containers that have my own initialization. In each container each model has its own toolbar. Now I need to create a new button in the toolbar of two models, when clicked, the same window will open as when clicking on the "properties" button on the toolbar. In this window, I will show the differences between the selected element of one model and the same element that is not selected from the second.
Thank you id advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this blog [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel) to extend and customize the property panel and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel) on how to slip in your own button/toolbar control. You may create two panels and have them displayed in pararrel to illustrate the comparison when the button is pressed.

And instead of the original properties inject your own data like below:

```
CustomPropertyPanel.prototype.setProperties = function (properties, options) {

        _this.addProperty('nameofproperty', 'valueofpropert', 'categoryname');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. 
I'm need one common panel to show difference property of two models.

Comment: I'm use [this code](https://repl.it/repls/UnkemptWheatModel), but I want to get only the properties that I need, and not all.
I will be very grateful if you help me get only the properties that I want, and not all the properties of the model.

Comment: I managed to remove all the properties and then add my properties, but this is not the most desirable way.
I also can not fix the height of the panel, could not tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Left comments in your code to address your issues: https://repl.it/repls/NanoGreatPatches

Comment: Thank you for your edit. You asked in the comments why I use "setProperties.call". I use this code, because without this code, when I click on any model element under the current property, a new property line is added to the Properties panel. I would be very grateful if you tell what is the reason.
I also can not fix the height of the panel and it is very unpleasant.

Comment: In [this](https://repl.it/repls/ThoroughWorthyRuntimeerror) code I get properties of first model. I need these properties to show them on the properties panel, but I don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Already explained about the style setting in my comment in the code sample. Simply pass the properties of the other model in when you set the properties for your custom panel...